# What can be the reason for missing files in /sbin?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, recovery

Recently a system with ubuntu installed stopped booting. While trying to fix things from rescue flash drive boot, I have run into a strange phenomenon: there was a big number of files missing/inaccessible. How can I determine the reason for that?

Not only I am unable to boot, I cannot chroot into the hard drive as well. I suspect the reasons are similar, though

[image]

Comment: Was the filesystem corrupted at some point? `fsck` might not have been able to make everything consistent/correct, which would cause something like this.

Comment: It is quite possible that it was. Is there a way, method or tool to properly explore that possibility and maybe fix the problem?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the system logs, if they're still intact. With regards to fixing it; I would highly doubt it. If `fsck` can't fix it, your filesystem is probably a lost cause. Copy whatever you need/can from it and just start over.